# ASP.NET core how to add a base controller action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am looking to add a base action that will be triggered at first before some of other actions, that is similar to the middleware concept in Node.js where one route will match one action by another action until the request is fulfilled and then later actions will not be triggered.

Like:

```
public class MyController : ControllerBase
    {
        public ReportDetailController(){}

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get")]
        public ActionResult one()
        {
            // base action
            // do some process base on request info
            // then
            return Next();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get")]
        public ActionResult two()
        {
            // base action
            // do some process base on request info
            // then
            return Next();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get")]
        public ActionResult three()
        {
            // fulfill here
            return Ok();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get")]
        public ActionResult three()
        {
            // will not come here
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to achieve this kind of operations in ASP.NET core? the base action need to be able to access the Request object information for pre-processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make an action call before the target action, or fullfill request before that, we need to use [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-6.0) class instead of `ControllerBase` since `Controller` implements IActionFilter and so you can override the `OnActionExecuting` method, which is a method that will be called before an endpoint action.

so,

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    public MyController(){}

    [NonAction]
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if(!user.exist)
        {
            // this will fulfill response
            // prevent actions below from being executed
            var re = new NotFoundObjectResult("Invalid User");
            context.Result = re;
        }
        else
        {
            // go to target action
        }
    }
        
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Target()
    {
        // will come here
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. Either you can create Middleware - or you can use `ActionFilterAttribute`. Since you already using a BaseController you can override the `OnActionExecutionAsync` method or `OnActionExecuting` method.

Here is an example which adds the Bearer token to HttpClient

```
public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
{
    if (User.Identity!.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        var idToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("id_token");
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", idToken);
    }

    await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
}
```

Comment: I put this method inside controller, but "OnActionExecutionAsync", no suitable method found to override

Comment: That is strange - [OnActionExecuting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.onactionexecuting?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040) and [OnActionExecutionAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.onactionexecutionasync?view=aspnetcore-6.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040)

Comment: I looked inside API Document, these methods are in Controller, whereas my controller is inherited from ControllerBase (no these methods), should I use Controller instead of ControllerBase? I saw people are using ControllerBase

Comment: No, you can override these methods in your controller. And if want it for all the controllers - either create a base controller (you can create a class and inherit it controllerbase and all the controllers inherit from it. Or create an action filter.

Comment: I finally made it worked by using Controller instead of ControllerBase, Thanks.